# How to get the cutil64D.lib file in cuda

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

I am trying to build a cuda program but it is giving me error as cutil64D.lib file not found.

I tried to build the file by opening the cutil_vs2008.sln solution file in vs 2008 and build it,but still I am not getting the cutil64D.lib.

Please suggest me something.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the platform to **x64** and the mode to **debug** when building cutil_vs2008.sln.

Comment: Thanks..I was missing that.
Now I got a folder x64 with release and debug folder in it.
Still I am not getting cutil64D.lib file,instead I am having one cutil64D.dll.embed.manifest file.

Comment: If the project built successfully then cutil64D.dll will be placed in the "bin\win64\Debug" directory, i.e. outside the "common" directory.

Comment: Incidentally, I strongly recommend you don't use cutil in a real application! It's purpose is only to simplify the code examples and it's not supported by NVIDIA.

Comment: The cutil64D.lib file should be in the common\lib\x64\Debug folder (note the "lib", the manifest file will be in common\x64\Debug without the lib).

Answer (score -1):

CUTIL is a simple utility library designed for use in the CUDA SDK samples, not part of CUDA.

You can build the solution under %SDK_Dir%\C\common\cutil_vs2008.sln by setting platform to **x64** and the mode to **debug**, then you will get what you want under %SDK_Dir%\C\common\lib\x64.

But, if you've already had this lib under some directory, setting platform and mode wrong could invite "can not find lib" error above.

Comment: Thanks,But I am not getting the lib file in that place which u have specified.

Do I need this lib file to build projects other than the samples???

Comment: Not necessary except you want to use function provided in this lib, the lib is designed for the SDK sample's error checking and something else.